# Android progress update with two values in asynctask

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I am implementing a progress bar (progress dialog) in an asynctask.

the parameters are:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>
```

and the progress update with integers works fine.

The onProgessUpdate:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
}
```

now I would like to update the dialog message as well at certain points. Is it possible to somehow give the onProgressUpdate an integer and a string, so that I could update the message?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a int and a string then either pass parameters of type Object (be careful though) or pass Strings and parse the one to an int, again be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that contains an integer and a string and use that instead of `Integer`. Then you can create one of those objects and pass it to `publishProgress()`.